# Python - find sum of list in dictionary & then find the list with the lowest value

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple score keeper for a card game.  The person with the lowest score wins.  I'm keeping players and scores in a dictionary:

```
players = {'bob': [3,6,4,3,7,3,6], 'joe': [3,7,5,9,9,7,8]}
```

I can sum each player's points by:

```
for player, score in players.items():
        print(f"\n{player.title()}'s final score is {sum(score)}")
```

Now I would like to announce the winner (person with the lowest score) but I can't get it to work.  This is what I've tried:

```
for points in players.values():
    score = sum(points)
winner = min(score)
print(f"The winner is {winner}!")
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: I think there are already good answers here, so I would just like to point at your mistake. When you say `score = sum(points)` you rewrite your `score` with a new value, so your final one will be the last value in the dictionary. Instead, you should say `score+=sum(points)`.Also, make sure that your `score` is defined before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
winner=min(players, key=lambda p:sum(players[p]))
```

Comment: Thanks @kuldipchaudhari  I'm still learning comprehensions and don't understand this part of the code:  p:sum(players[p]).  Do you have a few minutes to explain so I understand everything?

Answer (score 0):

```
print('The winner is {}'.format(min(players, key=lambda k: sum(players[k]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare a high number and an empty winner variable

create a `for` statement that print all the `dictionary` values name and points

```
point = 1000000; winner = ''

for name,points in players.items():
    temp = sum(points) #sum of all the num in the list
    if point > temp: # if point is > than the sum of the list replace the value of points
        point = temp
        winner = name

print(f"The winner is {winner}!")
```